# Not able to build ROS package with catkin_make. Confused by package tree

Tags: makefile, build, package, ros, catkin

I'm looking to run the main.launch stored in vehicle/launch/ from this github page
https://github.com/aureliopuebla/vehicle

I am very new at using ROS and have been learning, however I can't seem to be able to build these files.
If I try to use catkin_make on the parent folder it says that there is no existing 'src' folder.
If I go into the /vehicle folder there is a 'src' folder, but if I try to run catkin_make there, then it says that I have to run it at the root of the workspace. Which has me a bit stumped.

I have also tried to just run 'cmake ..', then 'make', and then 'sudo make install' in the /vehicle folder, but that just fills the /vehicle folder with copies of the other folders in the parent folder.

The reason why I want to build these packages is to be able to run the 'main.launch' file inside the '/vehicle/launch' folder with roslaunch, but it keeps saying that it can't find the other packages, no matter what I do.

Ready to clear up any questions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've been following the ROS tutorials for help, but have mostly been using http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages and http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CMakeLists.txt in the folder is the top-level CMakeLists. So You need to make this src folder yourself.
Just do the following:

```
$ mkdir -p vehicle_ws && cd vehicle_ws
$ git clone https://github.com/aureliopuebla/vehicle.git
$ mv vehicle src
$ catkin_make
```

This way it should work. Just leave out `mkdir -p vehicle_ws`, if you already created a workspace and instead just `cd` into it.

Comment: Great, that seemed to work. Tackling other problems now, but if necessary I'll make another post. Thank you. :)